# PySide2: TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

I have this PySide2 code which works on Linux with Python 2.7

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QBuffer, QByteArray

...

image = self.clipboard.image()
ba = QByteArray()
buffer = QBuffer(ba)
buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
image.save(buffer, "PNG")
return bytes(buffer.data())
```

But on windows with Python 3.6 it fails here:

```
  File "C:\....foo.py", line 93, in image_to_png
    return bytes(buffer.data())
```

Exception:

```
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What is the most simple way to get the PNG as bytes?

I would like to avoid to create a temporary file, since it is not needed for this context.

(I use PySide2, but I could switch to a different python-QT binding if you think it makes more sense. Please leave a comment if you think so)

Comment: Are you just converting old code to run on Python 3, or does it need to run on both 2.7 and 3.6?

Comment: On Python 3.6, what is the type of `buffer.data()` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring Up to now the same code base works in 2.7 and 3.6. It would be nice, if this could stay this way (at least for some months).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `QBuffer.data()` return type is `QByteArray` (which probably cannot be handled by the `bytes()` constructor), however `QByteArray.data()` return type is `bytes`. So, I think you should try `return buffer.data().data()` instead of `return bytes(buffer.data())`.

Comment: I think the online documentation is incorrect in this case, since it indicates `str` as the return type of `QByteArray.data()`: [link](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QByteArray.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QByteArray.data)

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around.

```
def image_to_png(image):
    temp_png = tempfile.mktemp('.png')
    image.save(temp_png)
    with io.open(temp_png, 'rb') as fd:
        content = fd.read()
    os.unlink(temp_png)
    return content
```

If possible, I would like to avoid the temporary file. Other solutions are welcome.